# Need help constructing a jQuery query

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues with a jQuery query.

Consider the following (crazy) HTML example:

```
<!-- this is the outermost condition -->
<div id="condition">

     <!-- this is a tag that I am looking for -->
     <input type="text" />

     <div id="condition">
          <input type="radio" />
     </div>

     <div>

          <div id="condition">
               <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>

          <!-- this is a tag that I am looking for -->
          <input type="text" />

     </div>
</div>
```

Given the above example-markup and the outer-most condition (seen in the top), how can I get all input elements WITHIN that condition, that are not members of inner conditions as well?

I've provided examples so you can see which tags I want the query to return.

Comment: Having duplicate id's on single page is invalid HTML. Consider using class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All html elements on a page should have a unique ID.

**That said, you could do something like this:**

```
// select the :first #condition
var $first = $("#condition:first");

// use map() to filter out inputs that don't meet our criteria
// and dump them into the inputs Array.
var inputs = $first.find("input").map(function() {

    // select parent with #condition ID
    var $parent = $(this).parent("#condition");

    // if parent == null or parent doesn't have any parents with ID = #condition
    // return the input, otherwise null, which removes it from the list
    return $parent.length == 0 || $parent.parents("#condition").length == 0 
        ? $(this) : null;
});
```

You end up with is an `Array` of inputs that are not wrapped in `#condition` or its parent is the first `#condition` element

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/EsYLx/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var found = $('#condition input').filter(function() {
    var parents = $(this).parents('.condition');
    return parents.length === 1 && parents[0].id === 'condition';
});
```

However, you're HTML is not only crazy, it's invalid. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, so you need to fix that first.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/R7MX4/

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you can't have 2 elements with the same ID - they must be unique, but if you went ahead and changed them to classes you could use something like:

```
$('#condition input:not(#condition #condition input)').doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:  Note you have 2 ids and ids should be unique.

```
$("#condition > input").html();
```

Comment: This is what I thought at first as well, but if you look at the OP's example, they want to include an input that's in a div that's a child of the outer condition.

Comment: I think I got it. Obviously this is easier if the ID's aren't the same but it may be very similar.